# filter not working in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to check if email has been already registered with different user by using validation rule `exist`. I wrote following code:

```
['email','exist',
'targetClass' => User::className(),
'targetAttribute' => 'email',
'message' => 'This email has already been taken. Please try another',
 'filter' => ['!=', 'user_id', Yii::$app->user->identity->id]],
```

It throws error every time, no matter if different user with the same email address exists or not. I want exact reverse validation from this code.

```
{
  "field": "email",
  "message": "This email has already been taken. Please try another"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should also set unique and target class

['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User']

Comment: Okay No problem, If you have any another query directly ask to me!

Answer (score 4):

You want to use

```
['email', 'unique'],
```

Also in your database you can mark column as unique (at least for MySQL I am using).

It will check for unique records in specified column.